# `ScrollToCaret` scrolls to the end of the selected text, how can I scroll to the begining of it?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, visibility

I am trying to make the selected text visible in a text box control after I found the text via a search box.

I tried the following code:

```
String searchText = "multiple lines of text.";
int position = textBox.Text.IndexOf(searchText);
textBox.SelectionStart = position;
textBox.SelectionLength = searchText.Length;
textBox.ScrollToCaret(); // caret is at the end of the selected text
```

`ScrollToCaret` method scrolls to the end of the selected text or the last line of the selected text. So if it spans to multiple lines and the height of this part is bigger than the height of textbox, part of the selected text may remain invisible.

Please notice I can't set the caret to the selection start too because I will loose highlight on the selected text.

How can I make sure the selected text is visible or in other words scroll to the first line of the selected text while keeping it highlighted?

Comment: I can't confirm, here the full selection in shown.

Comment: Suppose you have scrolled much down so your intended text which spans in multiple lines is hidden, now if you select that text and use ScrollToCaret then the scrollbar just stop on the end of the selected text, where the cared is placed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);    

int numLines = textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart);
//scroll to top
SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, 0x115, 6, 0); //WM_VSCROLL
//scroll numLines
SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, 0xB6, 0, numLines); //EM_LINESCROLL
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem...textbox scrolled to the end after ScrollToCaret. The problem was that all text was selected by default before my code started to run so SelectionLength was some big number and I didn't reset it before calling ScrollToCaret. Before calling ScrollToCaret make sure you set both SelectionStart and SelectionLenth to the desired values (in my case I set SelectionLength to 0).

And make sure your textbox is focused and visible (per MS documentation).